# Core Location not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location, ios8

I'm trying to use significant change location monitoring in iOS 8, but the didUpdateLocations method is never called. Here is the code for setting up the location manager:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

Despite calling `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, nothing pops up to ask the user to authorize it. I have set NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, and it still does not work. `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` and `didFailWithError` are also never called.
EDIT: I was able to get it to ask the user to allow location services, but even if you click allow it never shows the location.

Comment: This is happening mostly because people not add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to info.plist file but you are saying you have it already, what about the CLLocationManagerDelegate. [iOS 8 gps not enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821156/ios-8-gps-not-enabled/24821553#24821553)

Comment: I set the delegate as self, and I have <CLLocationManagerDelegate> in the header.

Comment: @charleyh: I am facing same issue. Did you got any solution?

Comment: I posted about some of the changes to the location manager in iOS 8 here: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: in this particular case (at least before the edit), the reason probably was that the location manager was not kept in memory long enough. see my answer below.

Comment: I found some more descriptive data/code at http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-fix-cllocationmanager-location.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is currently a bug in iOS8 beta5 which always deactivate geolocation service for your app (at least for mine).

Go in `settings > Privacy > Location services > Your app > Always`.

But I don't know why, but even if you set it to `Always` this setting will auto-deactivate, so please be patient and often return in the settings to configure again your app location.

Comment: i found that apps from app store is working fine but adhocs are not.

Comment: You're welcome, but I don't understand how you can still encounter this bug since the final ios8 version is available.

Comment: @Developer Are you sure that the reason for the different behaviour is the ad-hoc vs app-store? I think that the difference is between compiling with XCode 5 and XCode 6

Comment: @GeorgeSachpatzidis i found the issue was that i am not asking for requestWhenInUseAuthorization. which they had made compulsory in iOS 8

Answer (score 11):

Try declare `CLLocationManager *locationManager` in your header file then it works. Unless I have declare it as a global variable it does not ask for permission and update location.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:(id)self];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Delegate methods

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    NSLog(@"Getting Location");
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

info.plis

[image]

Comment: That still isn't working for me. The window pops up and I click allow, but it never actually gives the location.

Comment: Is it simulator or device? if it is simulator may be location is not selected in  menu / Debug / Location and wifi should be turned on

Comment: It is on the simulator, but I've set a location in the debug menu.

Comment: This is a bug - even the Maps App on the simulator won't show my location.

Comment: Simulator is not capable to find your location. The code above working fine for me with Xcode 6 beta 4.

Comment: Retested in beta4 and the problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this, after updating the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription  key, my code started getting location updates again!

Answer (score 5):

into .plist file add
[image]

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            [locationManager setDelegate:self];
            [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
 if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
            {
                [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            }
}

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
    {
     currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

All the steps look complete but run **:startUpdatingLocation** only after you check for **:didChangeAuthorizationStatus**.

At this point, please make sure that the authorizationStatus is not **kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined** or **kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied**.

If it is either, check for the string entries in info.plist.

If you feel all of it is correct, Make sure that you uninstall the app from the device. 
Perform a clean build and then run the app on the device.

Comment: yup, "reset content and settings" in the emulator and rebuilding/running the app solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem migrating my app to iOS 8.
As the original code as based on sample code provided by Apple 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html
I checked if it had been updated and it had. The main difference is in this function the bit relevant to iOS 8, has been commented. This worked for me.

```
- (void)startUpdatingCurrentLocation
{
 // if location services are restricted do nothing
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || 
       [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted )
    {
       return;
    }

// if locationManager does not currently exist, create it
   if (self.locationManager == nil)
   {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f; // we don't need to be any more accurate than 10m
   }

   // for iOS 8, specific user level permission is required,
   // "when-in-use" authorization grants access to the user's location
   //
  // important: be sure to include NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription along with its
  // explanation string in your Info.plist or startUpdatingLocation will not work.
  //
  if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
  {
      [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
  }

  [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

  [self showCurrentLocationSpinner:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

1. Background mode on in capabilities
2. `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`
3. `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`
4. `locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   [locationManager setDelegate:(id)self];
   [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`

   Thats in the beginning of app
5. `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in plist
6. Try to CMD + SHIFT + K
7. **Try to turn off iPhone and then turn on** - he had some cash in iOS 8 - so after 5 times - app don't ask permission to Core Location - that helped me

Answer (score 1):

The probable reason, why the authorization dialog is not shown with the OPs code, is that the location manager has to hang around for it to work.

Use a property or a static variable to keep `locationManager` in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because of the **WhenInUseAuthorization** is not enough for the "**Significant Location Change**" updates.

When i use **AlwaysAuthorization**, it just works.

i cannot find it in the docs. But you can check http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/. Under "Authorization Types" heading, it states that significant location updates need AlwaysAuthorization.

Comment: I found more CLLocation iOS 8 related issues fixes
http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-fix-cllocationmanager-location.html