# GPS Tracking in Xcode stopped working in Xcode 6 after working in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, user-tracking

I am going through a tutorial on youtube that teaches you how to track and trace a user's location on a map view. The tutorial comes with a copy of the code so I downloaded the code files and opened them up in Xcode. The first time that I opened the code in Xcode I had the newest Xcode 5. It ran just fine finding and tracing the location. About a day later Xcode 6 came out so I updated my Xcode to Xcode 6. When opening the code files in Xcode 6, the application would not preform correctly. I am getting an error that says...

```
2014-09-28 17:24:34.468 GPSTrack[1644:130866] Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

In the header file GPSTrackerViewController.h

```
//
//  GPSTrackViewController.h
//  GPSTrack
//
//  Created by Nick Barrowclough on 4/21/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 iSoftware Developers. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h> //import the mapkit framework

@interface GPSTrackViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, MKOverlay> {

    CLLocationManager *lm; //core lcoation manager instance

    NSMutableArray *trackPointArray; //Array to store location points

    //instaces from mapkit to draw trail on map
    MKMapRect routeRect;
    MKPolylineView* routeLineView;
    MKPolyline* routeLine;
}
- (IBAction)startTracking:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopTracking:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clearTrack:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;

@end
```

GPSTrackViewController.m

```
//
//  GPSTrackViewController.m
//  GPSTrack
//
//  Created by Nick Barrowclough on 4/21/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 iSoftware Developers. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GPSTrackViewController.h"

@interface GPSTrackViewController ()

@end

@implementation GPSTrackViewController

@synthesize mapview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    trackPointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)startTracking:(id)sender {
    //start location manager
    lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    lm.delegate = self;
    lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [lm startUpdatingLocation];

    mapview.delegate = self;
    mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    //get the latest location
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    //store latest location in stored track array;
    [trackPointArray addObject:currentLocation];

    //get latest location coordinates
    CLLocationDegrees Latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees Longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Latitude, Longitude);

    //zoom map to show users location
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationCoordinates, 1000, 1000);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapview regionThatFits:viewRegion]; [mapview setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    NSInteger numberOfSteps = trackPointArray.count;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++) {
        CLLocation *location = [trackPointArray objectAtIndex:index];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2 = location.coordinate;

        coordinates[index] = coordinate2;
    }

    MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
    [mapview addOverlay:polyLine];

    //NSLog(@"%@", trackPointArray);
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 4.0;

    return polylineView;
}

- (IBAction)stopTracking:(id)sender {
    //reset location manager and turn off GPS
    lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [lm stopUpdatingLocation];
    lm = nil;

    //stop shwing user location
    mapview.showsUserLocation = NO;

    //reset array fo tracks
    trackPointArray = nil;
    trackPointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)clearTrack:(id)sender {
    //remove overlay on mapview
    [mapview removeOverlays: mapview.overlays];
}


@end
```

Can someone please help me understand why the application is not running any more and give me some suggestions of what I need to do to get it up and running again.

Answer (score 1):

under base sdk 8 (which is what xcode 6 uses, I removed the xcode tag as it isn't IDE specific) you have to ask for authorisation first and have to have a plist key (a string saying why you need to use GPS)

the plist key depends on your needs is EITHER

- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

this SO question looks good:

[IOS 8 CLLocationManager Issue (Authorization Not Working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222188/ios-8-cllocationmanager-issue-authorization-not-working)

for detailed instructs, I can recommend (skimmed it):

http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: @Daji-Djan sorry it was a mistake. I accidentally down voted your question now the stack not allowing me to do an up vote.