# location updating in simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get the user's updated location by using core location framework.It is working in simulator, but not in ipad/iphone.I am using the following code to get it. In simulator, i am using freeway drive.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation: 
(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

 CLLocation *currentLocation=newLocation;
 NSLog(@"location : %@",currentLocation);

if(currentLocation !=nil)
{
 self.latitudelabel.text = [NSString 
 stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
 self.longitudelabel.text = [NSString  
 stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}

CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];

NSLog(@"Calc.distance%f",distance);

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^
(NSArray   *placemarks, NSError *error)
{

 if(error == nil && [placemarks count]>0)
 {
     placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
     NSLog(@"Country %@",placemark.country);
     NSLog(@"Area %@",placemark.administrativeArea);
     NSLog(@"City %@",placemark.locality);
     NSLog(@"Code %@",placemark.postalCode);
     NSLog(@"Road %@",placemark.thoroughfare);
     NSLog(@"Number %@",placemark.subThoroughfare);

     self.addresslabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ 
\n %@ %@    \n %@ \n %@",
 placemark.subThoroughfare,    placemark.thoroughfare,
                          placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                          placemark.administrativeArea,
                          placemark.country];

 }
 else
 {
     NSLog(@"tktk%@",error.debugDescription);

 }
}];

}
```

Comment: which device you have? and which is iOS version in device? iOS 8?

Comment: i have iPad and version is iOS 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go in `settings > Privacy > Location services > Your app > Always.`

You can also check other alternatives posted in the following question [Core Location not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874997/core-location-not-working-in-ios-8)