# iOS 8 CLLocationManager enterRegion: not getting called if use requestWhenInUseAuthorization

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager, clcircularregion

I'm trying to get being called the delegate method locationManager:didEnterRegion in iOS 8 for custom region. Here is the code:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(20, 20) radius:1000 identifier:@"asda"];
region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
region.notifyOnExit = YES;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

It does call method `locationManager:didStartMonitoringForRegion`, but it doesn't call "enter" or "exit" region methods.

The one more strange thing is that it DOES work if I use requestAlwaysAuthorization for locationManager. But I need to get it worked with "When In Use".

Note: In iOS7 it works for both WhenInUse and Always Authorization methods.

Comment: Hear your answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874997/core-location-not-working-in-ios-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

region monitoring - it's not working with `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`

check Apple Docs:
"`.. “when-in-use” ... Apps cannot use any services that automatically relaunch the app, such as region monitoring or the significant location change service`"

You must call  `requestAlwaysAuthorization`!!!
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization