# Not calling the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion in regionMonitoring

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I set some constant lat and long,Wherever i go it showing inside when i launch my app.stand end exit methods are never called.tried many time getting the same problem.
Here is my code Please help,Thanks in advance

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self initializeLocationServices];
}
-(void)initializeLocationServices
{
   NSLog(@"Started location services");

  _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  _locationManager.delegate = self;
  _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
   _locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

  [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; // to show authorisation popup
}

-(CLCircularRegion*)createRegion
{
// Test coordinates
CLLocationDegrees latitude = 12.908768;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = 77.652061;
CLLocationDistance radius = 50; // meters;

// If radius is too large, registration fails automatically, so limit the radius to the maximum value
if (radius > _locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance) {
    radius = _locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;
}

CLCircularRegion* region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) radius:radius identifier:@"TEST"];

region.notifyOnEntry = YES;
region.notifyOnExit = YES;


NSLog(@"Created region");

return region;
}

 -(void)monitorProximity
{
CLRegion *region = [self createRegion];

// Check if support is unavailable
if ( ![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLRegion class]]) {
    NSLog( @"Failed to initialise region monitoring: support unavailable");
    return;
}

// Check if authorised
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    NSLog( @"Failed to initialise region monitoring: app not authorized to use location services");
    return;
} else
{
    NSLog(@"Started monitoring proximity");
}

// Clear out any old regions to prevent buildup.
if ([_locationManager.monitoredRegions count] > 0)
{
    for (id obj in _locationManager.monitoredRegions)
        [_locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:obj];
}

[_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
}

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
 {
NSLog(@"Started monitoring for region: %@", [region description]);
[_locationManager requestStateForRegion:region]; // check if already inside region
}

 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Failed to start monitoring for region: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Failed Monitoring" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
  }


  -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
NSLog(@"didDetermineState");

if (state == CLRegionStateInside) {

    NSLog(@"inside");
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"inside" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;


} else if (state == CLRegionStateOutside) {
    NSLog(@"outside");
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"outside" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

} else {
    NSLog(@"unknown");
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"unknown" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

}

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
NSLog(@"didEnterRegion");
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"did enter region" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}

   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
 {
NSLog(@"didExitRegion");
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"did exit region" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
   }

   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
NSLog(@"Monitoring authorisation status is now: %@", status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ? @"authorized" : @"not authorized");

if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    [self monitorProximity];
}
  }
```

Comment: and where do you call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30728984/1702413

Comment: @TonyMkenu i added it now and checked then also it not worked