# CLLocationManager: didEnterRegion & didExitRegionAlert method did not called

Tags: iphone, location, cllocationmanager, geofencing, clregion

I am using **CLRegion** for **geofencing**. I monitored **CLCircularRegion** set for **notifyOnExit** and **notifyOnEntry**.
Here is my code:

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateGYM = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lng);
    CLCircularRegion *regionSet = [[CLCircularRegion alloc]initWithCenter:coordinateGYM radius:RADIUS identifier:strTitle];
    if(isExit)
    {
        regionSet.notifyOnExit = YES;
        regionSet.notifyOnEntry = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        regionSet.notifyOnExit = NO;
        regionSet.notifyOnEntry = YES;
    }
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:regionSet];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

Before monitor the region I try to removed all the region which motinored before it. Then I monitored with region. But it will directly invote 
**monitoringDidFailForRegion** delegate method with **Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 4.)** error. And it will not called delegate method.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
}
```

Can anyone help me what is error in my code?
Thanks,

Comment: locationManager.delegate = self;

Comment: @Rushabh yes, delegate is already set at there.

Comment: do you have implemented `requestAlwaysAuthorization`?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30728984/1702413

Comment: @TonyMkenu Yes I did it.

Comment: Your error mean `kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied` so you must check again if you don't have disabled "Background App Refresh" for the app in your device, if you have enabled Location Services. Reinstall the app and check if the app prompt the user to enable / allow the Location....

Comment: @TonyMkenu I got one solution of my question. I stop all the location which is monitored before and then register with new one. It will solve fail monitor issue. But I got another one. Now it will not called didDetermineState method when app is in Background Mode.