# How to notify user when he enters a CLLocation?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

**SITUATION:**

I followed the following tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift

---

**PROBLEM:**

The following functions never get triggered:

AppDelegate.swift

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region is CLCircularRegion {
        handleRegionEvent(region)
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region is CLCircularRegion {
        handleRegionEvent(region)
    }
}

func handleRegionEvent(region: CLRegion!) {

     print("Geofence triggered!")

    // Show an alert if application is active
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active {
        if let message = notefromRegionIdentifier(region.identifier) {
            if let viewController = window?.rootViewController {
                showSimpleAlertWithTitle("Congratulations", message: "You just found: " + message , viewController: viewController)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Otherwise present a local notification
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "You just found: " + notefromRegionIdentifier(region.identifier)!

        notification.soundName = "Default";
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
    }
}
```

---

**QUESTION:**

The tutorial was written for iOS 8. I am currently on iOS 9.3. What caused this issue in your opinion and how do I fix it ?

Comment: EDIT: The code works fine in the XCode simulator (where I can simulate movement from a point A to a point B in XCode with a gpx file), but not on my iPhone... Why ? There lies the solution for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure of two things :-

1.) You have added These to your `viewDidLoad()` :-

```
    locationManager.delegate = self 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Another alternative to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` and `startUpdatingLocation()` initialisation in specific to Swift 2.2, since in Swift 2.2 the string literals for selectors is deprecated, and instead there this new operator #selector that you need to be using. :-

you can also use :-

```
    locationManager.delegate = self 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone

    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
     if locationManager.respondsToSelector(#selector(locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
      //Prefer the FIRST ONE.
```

2.) You have updated your info.plist with :-

`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription : String :-> I need location.`

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription: String :-> I need location.`

`privacy - location usage description: String :-> I need location.`

Edit `I need location` according to the app's need

PS :- If it still not calls your `locationManager` functions

Simulator :- look for `location` settings of your app in your simulator settings.

Device: - Go in `settings > Privacy > Location services > Your app > Always.`

you also might find this explanation useful : - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26090094/6297658

Comment: Hi, it works on my simulator, but not on my phone. See my comment on my question.

Comment: Looks like it ! Thx :D

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show the code that you use to set up CL - which is probably where your problem lies.

Did you edit info.plist?

Are you requesting permission?

Did you call one of the start functions on the CL manager?

Comment: Let me edit my question. EDIT: done. And yes, I edited the info.plist as needed.

Answer (score 0):

initialize your location manager in app delegate on did finish launching