# Location Update not working

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am trying to make the location update happen even if the user exited the view going back to the previous view.
To make this happen i have created a separate class that handles my location update but I am encountering strange behavior.

First of all my authorization request was only popping up for a split second and than disappearing so i moved it back to the actual view.
However my location update is still not working. 
The location icon appears on the device but it never enters the didLocationUpdate function. Neither is it entering didFailWithError.
I'm pretty new to iOS so i have no idea what im doing wrong.

Here is my class:

```
import CoreLocation

class RouteLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

    var databasePath = ""
    override init(){

        super.init()

        let dirPaths =
            NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
                                                .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as NSString

        databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(
            "\\firstAscent.db")

        // For use in foreground
        locationManager =  CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


       //   locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        //  print("in location")

            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                print("System Services enabled")
                self.locationManager.delegate = self
                self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
                self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }


    }
    var isLocationMising = true


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

        let latitute = locValue.latitude
        let longitute = locValue.longitude
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)") //continues to make SQL query calls
```

I call it from the view with: `_ = RouteLocation()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38961606/6297658

Comment: I forgot to mention that this exact code worked when it was part of the view class.

Comment: You don't show the code where you allocate the `RouteLocation` instance, but from your description it sounds like you are allocating it in a local variable.  As soon as that function exits, the local variable is released, which means that your `CLLocationManager` instance is released.  You should allocate your `RouteLocation` object as a property of your AppDelegate or make it a singleton so that it is long-lived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `requestWhenInUse...` function runs asynchronously. It will show the dialog, but continue processing the rest of the code at the same time. Your app won't run correctly the first time (when the permission is given) even if everything else is correct.
2. Did you provide the `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` explanation string?
3. I think the way you instantiate the class it runs the init and instantly dies. There is nothing to retain it. 
   Therefore the `didUpdateLocation` can't be called.
4. If you need just one location, call `requestLocation`.

Comment: I have run the app multiple times and allowed Always authorization so point number one shouldnt be a problem. I do have the request authorization explanation string and it works correctly.  For point number 3 do you know how to fix that. I have a comment that i should allocate my RouteLocation as a property of my AppDelegate but I dont know how to do that. Also I dont want to run the locaion request forever just as long as it takes to gather accurate enough location to add to the database.

Comment: @Xitcod13 Not now, but first time somebody installs it it won't work correctly. To retain the object, how about for example creating a property `let routeLocation = RouteLocation()`  in the AppDelegate? If you need just one location entry consider `requestLocation`.

Comment: I might have to restructure my whole design. I need the location to start updating as soon as someone enters my view because I know they are trying to add that location to the database. The reason I have it in a separate class is because someone can than click the finish adding location button and the view will disappear even though the location can still continue to be gathered. So having the RouteLocation() in AppDelegate wont work unless I start and stop it from the view class somehow. (and it also be helpful to be able to have multiple instances of routeLocation at once)

Comment: Having it in a separate class isn't enough. If you want it to update location when your view controller from which the update was initiated is gone, you also need to ensure that your instance of that class continues to stick around. One way to do it is to instantiate it in app delegate. You don't have to start updating location there. You can, for example create a method `getLocation` that calls `requestLocation` and when you want the app to get the location info, you call app delegate->routeLocation->getLocation.

Answer (score 1):

*Everything is Perfect in your code but Delegate Method is not Correct*

**Write Delegate Method like this**

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {let latitute = locValue.latitude
    let longitute = locValue.longitude
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
```