# iOS 8 - an issue with GPS location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

I've simple class with GPS.
also i've serched and i have found no solutions for me.

[This example doesn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821156/ios-8-gps-not-enabled)

So my here it is my code:

```
@interface MFPointViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation MFPointViewController{

    CLLocationManager *manager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.helper = [[AppHelper alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc ]init];

    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    manager.delegate = self;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.helper setBackgroundToVIew:self.view];


}

#pragma  mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [self.helper alert:@"Attenzione" message:@"Turn on geolocation" delegate:self];


}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if(currentLocation != nil){
        NSString *Glat;
        NSString *Glong;

        Glat  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        Glong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        // Here goes my logics      

    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

If i use one device with iOS 7 - this code work's fine.

On iOS 8 no.
What can it be?

Thanks to all!

Comment: So what happens? Is there a crash or error? Is didUpdateToLocation: triggered?

Comment: NO it's no crash.
if i do next code:
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
on currentLocation i've nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before startUpdateLocation

```
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Comment: You need to do BOTH things, nero's code and my plist code.

Comment: Also, use -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

Comment: Now my method viewDidLoad is:
`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc ]init];
    
    if([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {

        [manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    
    manager.delegate = self;

    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
`

my Info.plist:
`<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>If you want to see our access points surfree, you need to enable geolocation.</string>
`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to nerowolfe's code you also need to add at least one of these to your Info.plist

- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Put a descriptive string in them telling the user why you want to access their GPS.

Comment: BTW how do you localize that descriptive string?

Comment: From Apple's Docs: Localized values are not stored in the Info.plist file itself. Instead, you store the values for a particular localization in a strings file with the name InfoPlist.strings. You place this file in the same language-specific project directory that you use to store other resources for the same localization. The contents of the InfoPlist.strings file are the individual keys you want localized and the appropriately translated value...

Comment: You can localize your plist file by selecting it in the project navigator and press "Localize.." in the File Inspector. xcode will create a new plist for the selected language

Comment: Come on, just google one of the bulleted keys above! Ok, let me do that for you. First hit: http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/getting-gps-location-using-core-location-in-ios-8-vs-ios-7/